# How to parse Python set-inside-list structure into text?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I have the following strange format I am trying to parse.

The data structure I am trying to parse is a "set" of key-value pairs in a list:

```
[{'key1:value1', 'key2:value2', 'key3:value3',...}]
```

That's the only data I have, and it needs to be processed. I don't think this can be described as a Python data structure, but I need to parse this to become a string like

```
'key1:value1, key2:value2, key3:value3'.
```

Is this doable?

EDIT: Yes, it is `key:value`, not `key`:`value`

Also, this is Python3.x

Comment: Are we dealing with `'key1:value1'` or `'key1':'value1'`?

Comment: @Efferalgan We are dealing with `'key1:value1'` actually

Comment: @ShanZhengYang then it's not `dict` object, it's a `set`

Comment: @ShanZhengYang i've updated my answer, so now it contains two approaches, with `list` of `dict` and `list` of `set`

Comment: @RahulKP OP says that we are dealing with `'key:value'`

Comment: @RahulKP Yep, it's `'key:value'`

Comment: @ShanZhengYang Then it's not a dictionary, It'a  a set only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over `.items()` and formatting differently then previous answers.

If your data is the following: `list` of `dict` objects then

```
>>> data = [{'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2', 'key3':'value3'}] 
>>> ', '.join('{0}:{1}'.format(*item) for item in my_dict.items() for my_dict in data)
'key2:value2, key3:value3, key1:value1'
```

If you data is the `list` of `set` objects then approach is simpler

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> data = [{'key1:value1', 'key2:value2', 'key3:value3'}] 
>>> ', '.join(chain.from_iterable(data))
'key1:value1, key2:value2, key3:value3'
```

**UPD**

NOTE: order can be changed, because `set` and `dict` objects are not ordered.

Comment: Let's say it absolutely had to be kept in order---what would be the approach then?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang you can't do that with `set`, nor `dict`. You can use `list` or `OrderedDict` from `collections` package.

Comment: Thanks. You mean convert the structure into an OrderedDict first ?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang no, your data initially should've been `OrderedDict` or `list`. If you initial data was more like `set` then i suggest you make it `list` then. So instead of having `data = [{'key1:value1', 'key2:value2', 'key3:value3'}] `, you should be having `data = [['key1:value1', 'key2:value2', 'key3:value3'}]] `.

Comment: What about if the original data is `data = ['key1:value1', 'key2:value2', 'key3:value3']`? That is, a list of values which must be parsed into kye value pairs, `key`:`value`?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang then to make it `'key1:value1, key2:value2, key3:value3'` you just need that `' ,'.join(data)`

Comment: I understand how this pattern works now. Thanks for teaching me this!

Answer (score 1):

```
', '.join('{0}:{1}'.format(key, value) for key, value in my_dict.iteritems() for my_dict in my_list)
```

where my_list is name of your list variable

Comment: How could I save this as a variable?

Comment: Using Python3.x as well

Answer (score 1):

Since your structure (let's call it `myStruct`) is a `set` rather than a `dict`, the following code should do what you want:

```
result = ", ".join([x for x in myStruct[0]])
```

Beware, a `set` is not ordered, so you might end up with something like `'key2:value2, key1:value1, key3:value3'`.

Comment: Thanks for this--- 
Let's say it absolutely had to be kept in order---what would be the approach then?

Comment: Then you would have to use another format than a `set` (`list` or `OrderedDict` would work). Here, `{'key1:value1', 'key2:value2'}` is **exactly the same** as `{'key2:value2', 'key1:value1'}`. The problem is not that you cannot keep the same order, it is that there is no order to be kept in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I would use itertools

```
d = {'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2', 'key3':'value3'}

for k, v in d.iteritems():
    print k + v + ',',
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: I believe that will be due to the fact that in your question the dictionary is 'key:value' rather than 'key':'value'

Comment: @ShanZhengYang that because `.iteritems()` is from python 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
print ', '.join(i for x in list_of_set for i in x)
```

If it's `set` there is no issue with the parsing. The code is equals to

```
output = ''
for x in list of_set:
    for i in x: 
        output += i
print output
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a list whose only element is a dictionary, and you want to get all the keys-value pairs from that dictionary and put them into a string?

If so, try something like this:

```
d = yourList[0]
s = ""
for key in d.keys():
    s += key + ":" + d[key] + ", "
s = s[:-2] #To trim off the last comma that gets added
```

Comment: This is absolutely ineffective.

Comment: @vishes_shell, how so?

Comment: Concatenating strings is better to proceed with `.join()`. `yourList` could be not one element list. Make loop over `dict` object is better with `for key, value in dict.items()`.